# java cyclic annotations

Tags: java, annotations

I want to create tree structure with annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyNode {
     String name();
     MyNode next() default null;
}
```

but compiler tells that it is cycle and hence it is not allowed.

I wonder why it is not allowed and how can I make something like it?

Comment: Are you just experimenting with annotations or do you have a particular problem in mind?

Comment: @beny23, I need to specify path, like very simplified XPath or path to directory on file system `/path/to/an/element`

Comment: I don't quite understand why you want to create a linked list of annotations then? Wouldn't a string value with a path be sufficient for your needs?

Comment: I do not want to use string as there will be a lot of clutter with extracting path elements. I could simply use string array, but what if I will need to extend this linked list to a tree with more children (e.g. two left() and right())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Annotations are compile-time constants.
2. Annotation members can only be compile-time constants (Strings, primitives, enums, annotations, class literals).
3. Anything that references itself can't be a constant, so an annotation can't reference itself.

The funny thing is: there is a part of the Java Language specification that seems to contradict this:

> An annotation on an annotation type declaration is known as a
>   meta-annotation. An annotation type may be used to annotate its own
>   declaration. More generally, circularities in the transitive closure
>   of the "annotates" relation are permitted. For example, it is legal to
>   annotate an annotation type declaration with another annotation type,
>   and to annotate the latter type's declaration with the former type.
>   (The pre-defined meta-annotation types contain several such
>   circularities.)
>   [[Source](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/interfaces.html#9.7)]

But I get a compile error for both this (annotation references itself):

```
public @interface Funky {
    Funky funky();
}
```

and this (two annotations reference each other):

```
public @interface Funky {
    Monkey monkey();
}
public @interface Monkey {
    Funky funky();
}
```

Comment: Heh, seems to be impossible :(. Am I right that annotation itself is not saved in .class file (like String or int), but created at runtime?

Comment: @misha the annotation declaration itself resides in a .class file (an annotation is an interface). Whether the annotations used appear in the annotated classes depends on the ` @Retention`

Comment: I think that part of the specification refers to code like this, which compiles without errors: `@NewAnnotationType public @interface NewAnnotationType { }`

Comment: @Jörn You're right of course. That's why the annotation processor works in cycles, I guess :-)

Comment: @sean-patrick-floyd, 
`Anything that references itself can't be a constant, so an annotation can't reference itself`. Could you explain it more detailed. There two different objects but of the same type. And one of the objects holds link to the other object. What is the problem to put them together. When there are two objects of different types everything works perfectly: `@interface Annotation1 {Annotation2 annot();}`

Comment: @misha the requirement is that any member of an annotation is a compile-time constant. While the compiler is smart enough to recursively compile member types first, there is no time during the compilation of your annotation class where the compiler holds a compiled version of this class, which he would need to make sure the member is a compile-time constant

Answer (score 3):

It is not a tree structure, just the linear list. Try to use array to simplify declaration.

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyNode {
     String name();
}
```

And wrap:

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface MyNodes {
     MyNode[] value();
}
```

Now, just declare as array:

```
@MyNodes({ 
    @MyNode(name = "name1"),
    @MyNode(name = "name2")
})
public class MyClass {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really need this, you may want to use the Sun Java 5 compiler, where this restriction is not enforced.

But maybe a better solution is to store the nodes in an array and let each node have the index(es) of it's child node(s).

Comment: *you may want to use the Sun Java 5 compiler* Please don't. JDK 7 is here, this is not the time to jump back to 1.5

Comment: Therefore I suggested a better solution.